# Get certain documents from collection in Firestore by a field

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm doing a web application in Angular 6 and [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2). I'm getting all documents in a collection but, now I need to query those documents to get all the documents with the field `role.moderator == true`.

```
  private usersCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<User>;
  users: Observable<UserId[]>;
  moderators: Observable<UserId[]>;

  constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore
  ) {
    this.usersCollection = afs.collection<User>(config.collection_users);

    this.users = this.usersCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as User;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return {id, ...data};
      }))
    );

    // Query this.users ?
  }
```

The interface of a User is:

```
export interface User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  emailAddress: string;
  roles: Roles;
  officeAssignedId: string;
}

export interface UserId extends User {
  id: string;
}

export interface Roles {
  administrator?: boolean;
  moderator?: boolean;
}
```

To get all users with the role of moderator, I was doing:

```
getUsersWithModeratorRole() {
    return this.afs.collection<User>(
      config.collection_users,
      ref => ref.where('roles.moderator', '==', true)).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as User;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return {id, ...data};
      }))
    );
  }
```

**The problem is:**

1. I need to subscribe and unsubscribe inside of the component.
2. I feel that I am duplicating code because I already have the
   documents (`this.users`), I just need to query them by a field.
3. I was doing `.take(1)` and `.toPromise()` inside of my `getUsersWithModeratorRole`
   method but, only returns me one user and I need all. I thought that with `.take(1)` will grab all.

My goal is to query the collection that I already have (`this.users`) to find all users who has the field `role.moderator == true` or convert the `getUsersWithModeratorRole` method to a Promise correctly to grab all.

Comment: I struggle with understanding what you are asking about / what you want to achieve, could you rephrase it? If you want to get all the users with role.moderator === true, and you have already retrieved all the users, you can do a filter on this users array. If you have not retrieved all the users, and you want to query for all the users with role.moderator === true directly from Firestore, then your getUsersWithModeratorRole() method looks correct.

Comment: @SnorreDan Hi, thanks for answering me back. I don't want to subscribe and unsubscribe in the component. I would like to convert it to a Promise or, due to I already have all the documents inside of `this.users` in the service, how can I query `this.users` before sending the result to my component. I mean, query `this.users` to get only the users with the field  `role.moderator == true`. With my `getUsersWithModeratorRole` method I feel that I am duplicating code unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method that returns an Observable on your service like this:

```
getUsersWithModeratorRole(): Observable<UserId[]> {
  return this.users.pipe(
    map(users => users.filter(user => user.roles.moderator === true))
  );
}
```

Or if you want it to return a promise, I think it would be something like this:

```
getUsersWithModeratorRole(): Promise<UserId[]> {
  return this.users.pipe(
    take(1),
    map(users => users.filter(user => user.roles.moderator === true))
  ).toPromise();
}
```

Comment: In the second snippet, I think you have an error, should be like this: `return this.users.pipe(
      map(users => users.filter(user => user.roles.moderator === true))
    ).toPromise();`. However, is not working for me, the method keeps running and never end.

Comment: The first snippet, the `Observable`, is working but, I would prefer the `Promise`, I hope you can help me to find the issue in the snippet of the `Promise`, about why it's not finishing and not returning data.

Comment: You were correct about the errors, I have updated my answer. I am not that familiar with how the toPromise() works, but could you try adding a "publishReplay(1)" in the pipe in your service? So you would need to add a comma at the end of line 15 and then add a new line number 16 with "publishReplay(1)".

Comment: Hi, is not working for me either. The method never ends.

Comment: I am quite sure I know the problem now. For toPromise() to work, the Observable needs to complete. I have added a "take(1)" in the code example above to make it complete.

Comment: I tried that, I mentioned that function in the details of my question, the problem with `.take(1)` is that it only returns one value, and I need all. At least, in my case only returns one value.

Comment: .take(1) only returns one event with one value yes, but if that value is an array, as in this case, it will still give you the entire array. If I have understood you correctly, this should solve your problem.